# I want to make certain one row returned from select into using mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
stored procedure
(IN in_myval varchar)
SELECT myid
INTO @myid
FROM sometable
WHERE myval = in_myval;

IF (@myid IS NULL OR @myid='') THEN <=not working
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'No id found';
```

I want to make certain that only *one* @myid, a *non-empty* varchar, was returned. I will exit if this condition is not true.

Comment: if you select multiple values into a single variable - you will get an exception.  You can catch that exception, or you can change the query to select a DISTINCT value or LIMIT 1 number of rows

Comment: To check non-empty ... not(Is null or ='')?

Answer (score 0):

You could first count the number of occurrences

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Addsomething(
IN in_myval varchar )
BEGIN
    DECLARE C INT;

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO C
    FROM sometable
    WHERE myval = in_myval;

    -- check if count = 1 exists
    IF(C != 1) THEN 
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'No id found'';
    END IF;
    SELECT myid
    INTO @myid
   FROM sometable
    WHERE myval = in_myval;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you want to ensure one row, use a function,

```
select max(myid) as myid, count(*) as N
```

That way, you know you have one value for `myid`, and whether or not it's unique.

I'm not a MySQL user, so don't know the specifics of how to set variables or report errors in a stored procedure on your system.  But the above strategy will get you the two bits you're looking for.